# Ruby on rails list to columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to create ruby on rails list(index page) like this:
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
10| 11|
and so on.

Comment: You really want to skip the vertical bar after 3, 6 and 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google query you're looking for is "pagination".

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to check out the [will_paginate](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem.